# How to write htaccess 301 redirect - need to remove some "?" in query string

Tags: .htaccess, http-redirect

I can't write a working 301 redirect for some specific pages.

I have got old url with "?" in the string, like :

```
/old-url?page=2
/old-url?added1&page=2
/old-url?page=3
```

So, if it's possible, I would like to redirect all these pageto a unique /new-page.

Can you please help me ?

Usually I use the code:

```
RedirectPermanent /old-url https://www.new-url.tld
```

It is working fine for all pages, except for these url.

Comment: Do you want to redirect *every* link to `/old-url` or just ones that contain a query string?

Comment: Hi,
Here are the complete links. I just changed the domain name to "website.com"

http://www.website.com/livre-d-or?page=2
http://www.website.com/livre-d-or?page=4
https://www.website.com/livre-d-or?added1&page=3

All this 3 pages (and others with the same livre-d-or?xxx) should be redirected to :
https://www.website.com/avis-dj-mariage-64/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=2$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^added1&page=2$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=3$
RewriteRule ^/?old-url$ /new-page [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded and active for that location inside the http server.

That implementation will work likewise, in the central http server's host configuration (the preferred place to implement such rules) or also a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), if that feature has been enabled and the file is located in the http hosts `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.

---

Update motivated by the OPs comment to this answer:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=\d+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^added1&page=\d+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=\d+$
RewriteRule ^/?livre-d-or/?$ /avis-dj-mariage-64 [R=301,L,QSD]
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you, but it doesn't work. To be sure to have given the correct information, here are the complete links. I just changed the domain name to "website.com"

http://www.website.com/livre-d-or?page=2
http://www.website.com/livre-d-or?page=4
https://www.website.com/livre-d-or?added1&page=3

The page to which all these links should go:
https://www.website.com/avis-dj-mariage-64/

Nothing happened with your code (still 404 error).

Comment: @Insky you will of course need to modify the `^/?old-url$` part to match your URL path. And the query string parameter values are different than in the initial examples you had given as well. If you don't want to match _specific_ numbers only, allow for arbitrary digits (or numbers) using a a character class instead.

Comment: @Insky Also make sure that the rewriting module is really loaded and activated. Also that you used the `AllowOverride` directive to allow such rules _if you are using a distributed configuration file (".htaccess")_ ...

Comment: @Insky I added an update to the answer that accepts arbitrary numbers in the query string and uses the specific paths you now mention in your comment above.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried the updated code and I still saw no effect... then I just put those lines upper in the htaccess file and it is working now! There must have been a precedence issue with other rules already in the file.

All is ok now ! Kind Regards

Comment: @Insky Sure, the order of rules is important. You never mentioned any existing rules in your question or comments. So I did not mention that either.